# ExoPlayer cannot play live streams With resolution 1080p

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to play some m3u8 urls but it seems exoplayer cannot play them if they are 1080p or more it only plays streams with resolution 720p and less. Is there a way to make exoplayer to play these streams with 1080p? i'm leaving even my streamplayer.java here if needed, also hardware acceleration is "true". if someone has had this problem with exoplayer with their app please give me some advice since im a new developer to android and i'm struggling to create my first app. Thankyou in advance.

```
        mediaDataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(true);

        mainHandler = new Handler();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this);

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();


        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector, loadControl);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        playerView.setUseController(true);
        playerView.requestFocus();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri,null);

        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTimelineChanged: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTracksChanged: " + trackGroups.length);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingChanged: " + isLoading);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: " + playWhenReady);
                if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerError: ", error);
                player.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPositionDiscontinuity: true");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });

        Log.d("INFO", "ActivityVideoPlayer");

    }
    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, String overrideExtension) {
        int type = TextUtils.isEmpty(overrideExtension) ? Util.inferContentType(uri)
                : Util.inferContentType("." + overrideExtension);
        switch (type) {
            case C.TYPE_SS:
                return new SsMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultSsChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), buildDataSourceFactory(true)).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_DASH:
                return new DashMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), buildDataSourceFactory(true)).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_HLS:
                return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_OTHER:
                return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
            default: {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
            }
        }
    }

    private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
        return buildDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
    }

    public DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, bandwidthMeter,
                buildHttpDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter));
    }

    public HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayer"), bandwidthMeter);
    }
```

Comment: What is the codec string for the “1080p” stream? It will be something like “avc1.640029” the last two characters are the “level”. I’m going to guess “2a” Anything over 28 or 29 has more limited support on mobile devices and low cost hardware.